# How to get values from option-list into consecutive input-fields by onclick-function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a html-form to read out data from a database.
By clicking a button, there is the possibility to create additional input fields.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="productinput" name="productinput[]" class="awesomplete" list="productselect" size="20"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="productinput2" name="productinput[]" class="awesomplete" list="productselect" size="20"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="text" id="productinput3" name="productinput[]" class="awesomplete" list="productselect" size="20"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<script>
   var counter = 1;

   var limit = 10;

   function addInput(divName){

        if (counter == limit)  {

             alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");

        }

        else {

   // Create new div
   var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
   newdiv.innerHTML = '<br><input type="text" name="productinput[]" class="awesomplete" list="productinputselect" size="20"/>';
   document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);

   // Re instantiate Awesomplete
   new Awesomplete(newdiv.querySelector('input'), { list: document.querySelector('#productinputselect') });

   // Set counter
   counter++;

        }

   }
</script>
<div id="dynamicInput">
   <b></b><input type="text" id="productinput4" name="productinput[]" class="awesomplete" list="productinputselect" size="20"/>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Additional Input Field" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
<select name="productselect" id="productselect" size="9" onclick="sendproductnameinput()">
<?php
   include("../files/zugriff.inc.php");     // database access

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM product_main ORDER BY Name";
   $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo '<option class="optproduct" value='. $row['Name'] . '>' . $row['Name']. '</option>';
     echo '<br>';
    }
   mysqli_close($db);
   ?>
</select>
```

So far, this works fine!

By using the following javascript-function the selected value from the -list is displayed in the first input-field.

```
function sendproductnameinput() {
    document.formdatabase.productinput.value = document.formdatabase. productselect.value;
}
```

How can I get the next selected value in the second input-field and so on? This function should work in the additionally added fields, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
for (var i = document.formdatabase.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        document.formdatabase[i].value = document.formdatabase.productselect.value;
    }
```

Your Select seems to be not Multiple select, so I suppose you want to put the same selected value in each input.

And if multiple select than you can use this:

```
function getSelectValues(select) {
  var result = [];
  var options = select && select.options;
  var opt;

  for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    opt = options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
      result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function sendproductnameinput() {
    var selected = getSelectValues(document.formdatabase.productselect);

    for (var i = document.formdatabase.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(i < selected.length) {
            document.formdatabase[i].value = selected[i];
        }
    }
}
```

here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/586menbv/16/

Comment: Thanks B. Assem for your suggestion! I think, I have to add some more information: the Select gets numerous values from the database and the input-fields should get different values from the list.

Comment: I added the code that you can use if the Select can accepts more than one value, but in that case your html must be :
`<select name="productselect" id="productselect" size="9" onclick="sendproductnameinput()" multiple>`

Comment: Yes, B. Assem, I tried your code, but unfortunately it didn´t work. I got no values in the input-fields, not even in the first one.

Comment: @Columbus here is a working fiddle based on my answer https://jsfiddle.net/586menbv/9/

Comment: Thanks for the working fiddle that I just tested! The remaining problem is that the clicked values are only sent to the first input field and I would like to have them in the following way: 1st clicked value -> 1st input, 2nd clicked value -> 2nd input, 3rd clicked value -> 3rd input and so on.

Comment: I just noticed that it depends on the input-field´s ID, which input-field receives the clicked value. This means, that the function would have to know the ID of the next free input-field. And for the additionally added input-fields ID´s in ascending order would be required.

Comment: so you want that if you choose the second value in your select, the value is set in the second input even if the first input is empty?

Comment: Or you want that : The 1st Selected value is always copied in the First Input (what if that input is already populated with a value? what to do if we click to deselect a selected value... Taking in consideration the selection order, means tracking each click for selection and deselection and needs to deal with a lot of possibilities!!)

Comment: I think that I gave you the proper code to loop on your input and also to get your selected options, so you can use that to implement your logic after properly defining your need. I'm not sure that I will be of more help :) ( it is up to you to choose my answer as the right one or not, or at least upvote it ;) )

Comment: Thanks B. Assem, I really appreciate your help, and I´m sorry for not having expressed myself very well! What I wanted is that: any selected value from the option-list (not necessarily the first in the list) should be sent to the first input-field. If a second value from the option-list is selected (whichever), this value should be sent to the second input-field and so on. If the value of an already populated input is deselected, the next selected value should be sent to this input, since this input is the first empty input with the lowest order-number.

Comment: Thanks B. Assem, it worked! :) I have just chosen your answer as the right one! Primarily, I thought that the selection would work without pressing Strg-button, that´s why it did not. I wish you all the best for the upcoming year! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on where the function `sendproductnameinput()` is defined, but if the variable `counter` is visible from it's scope, I would dare to write something like this:

```
var timesSomethingSelected = 1;

function sendproductnameinput() {
    var productinput = 'productinput';

    if(timesSomethingSelected > 1) {
        productinput += timesSomethingSelected;
        timesSomethingSelected++;
    } else if(timesSomethingSelected == counter) {
        //Do something if there aren't more inputs.
    }

    document.formdatabase[productinput].value = document.formdatabase. productselect.value;
}
```